# Counting different combinations

Tags: sql-server, combinations

I have a data set that looks like this (user ID in one column and medicine name in another - users can have multiple rows if they use multiple medicines). I want to find the most common combinations of medicines used e.g. 5 people use medicine a and b and 4 people use medicine a,b and c

Expected output
[image]

Data frame
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I am currently blocked from the imgur.com domain - so I cannot see either of the 2 images - hence your question in unintelligible to me. If you pasted code and/or data as text that problem would not occur. Please don't use images of code or data.

Comment: Each database vendor implements "sql"  differently so to get the most suitable syntax for your question please identify the database you use e.g. mysql, Oracle, MS sql server (edit the tags)

Answer (score 0):

You have to count unique number of users per medicine

```
SELECT medicine
, count(unique user_id) as uniq_users
, count(user_id) as total_users
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY medicine
```

list of medicines per user

```
SELECT user_id
, medicine
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY user_id
, medicine
```

However, if this is the table structure, it's very wrong.. you should read more about "database normal forms"

Comment: Thanks - I want the different combinations of medicines that people use rather than the individual counts of people that use each medicine

Comment: check the edit now